# Component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled in React /Next js

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

client.js:1 Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components

What i did was my input field was recieving a value-can be from anywhere , which was put into value prop/attribute
Therefore recieving the mentioned error

In my case i am recieving it via query parameter -url
According to my assumption i think it is undefined in the begiining but gets filled later

Router Setup
`    const router = useRouter();

```
// Get the query parameter from the URL
 const { passwordResetToken, emailVerificationToken,firstName,lastName,email } = router.query;
 const emailId= email; 
 const fullName = firstName + ' ' + lastName;

 console.log(router.query);
  console.log(passwordResetToken,emailVerificationToken,firstName,lastName,email );`
```

Input Field
`<div className="flex flex-col gap-[4px] w-full "> <div className=""> <label className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" htmlFor="name" > Email* </label> </div> <div className=""> <input className={ w-full placeholder:font-normal text-base  text-gray-500`}
name="email"
id="email"
placeholder="Enter your email"
value={email}
disabled
/>

</div`

Same logic for this input field  field works

```
`<div className="flex flex-col gap-[4px] w-full  ">
              <div className="">
                <label
                  className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                  htmlFor="name"
                >
                  Full Name*
                </label>
              </div>
              <div className="">
                <input
                type="email"
                  className={`input_conatiner w-full placeholder:font-normal text-base text-gray-500`}
                  name="full_Name"
                  id="full_Name"
                  value={fullName}
                  disabled
                />
              </div>
            </div>`
```

I think concat operator does the trick-it converts undefined to a string of value undefined

Answer (score 0):

to Problem solve Error

The component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled in React /Next js

is just adding an OnChange Function on the input.